# why this code isn't working in real-time pleace cheack this code

Tags: java, android, google-cloud-firestore

this code isn't working in **real-time**.. it works only whenever I restart/refresh the app. I am using Cloud **Firestore**. plzz change code am noob help me. & sorry For My bad English

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

```
 public class Category_List_Activity extends BaseActivity {
    
        List<CardModel> list = new ArrayList<>();
        RecyclerView recyclerView;
        RecyclerAdapter adapter;
        android.app.AlertDialog dialog;
        private static final String TAG = "CategoryListActivity";
        FirebaseFirestore db;
        String name, id,node,lastid,time;
        boolean islast;
        SessionManager sessionManager;
        LinearLayout banner;
        private InterstitialAd interstitial;
        TextView settitel;
    
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.category_list);
            FirebaseApp.initializeApp(this);
            db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
            Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
            banner = findViewById(R.id.banner_bottom_main);
            sessionManager=new SessionManager(this);
            getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SECURE, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SECURE);
    
            StartAppAd.showAd(this);
    
            new AdsHelper().createBanner(this, banner, sessionManager.getBanner());
    
            if (bundle != null) {
                name = bundle.getString("name");
                id = bundle.getString("id");
                lastid = bundle.getString("lastid");
                node=bundle.getString("node");
                islast=bundle.getBoolean("islast");
            }
    ///////////////////////////Action bar custiom//////////////////////////////////////////
            ImageView imgFavorite = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.previous);
            imgFavorite.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    onBackPressed();
                }
            });
    
            ImageView imgFavorsite = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.refrashing);
            imgFavorsite.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    getData();
                }
            });
    
    
            settitel = findViewById(R.id.event_name);
            settitel.setText(name);
    ///////////////////////Action bar custiom end///////////////////////
    
    
            recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.rec);
            adapter = new RecyclerAdapter(list, this);
            recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
            AutoFitGridLayoutManager layoutManager = new AutoFitGridLayoutManager(this, 10000);
            recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
    //        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(this,1));
    
            recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    
    
            getData();
    
            if(isCastApiAvailable()) {
                castContext = CastContext.getSharedInstance(this);
                if (castContext.getCastState() == CastState.CONNECTED) {
                    findViewById(R.id.castMiniController).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }else{
                    findViewById(R.id.castMiniController).setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }
            }else{
                findViewById(R.id.castMiniController).setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
    
    
    
        }
    
        CastContext castContext;
    
    
        @Override
        protected void onResume() {
            super.onResume();
    
            try {
                if (HelperClass.vpn(this)) {
                    finish();
                }
            }catch (Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
    
        }
    
    
    
        @Override
        public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(@NonNull Menu menu) {
            // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
            getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
            return true;
        }
    
    
        @Override
        public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
            if(item.getItemId() == R.id.refrish){
                getData();
                return true;
            }
    
            else if (item.getItemId() == android.R.id.home) {
                onBackPressed();
            }
    
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    
    
    //    @Override
    //    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    //
    //        if (item.getItemId() == android.R.id.home) {
    //            onBackPressed();
    //        }
    //
    //        return true;
    //    }
    
        //////////////////sports diglo start///////////////
        @Override
        public void onDestroy() {
            dismissProgressDialog();
            super.onDestroy();
        }
        private void showProgressDialog() {
            if (dialog == null) {
                dialog = new SpotsDialog.Builder().setContext(this).build();
                dialog.setMessage("Please wait...");
                dialog.setCancelable(false);
            }
            dialog.show();
        }
    
        private void dismissProgressDialog() {
            if (dialog != null && dialog.isShowing()) {
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        }
    //////////////////sports diglo end///////////////
    
    
    
    
        private void getData() {
            showProgressDialog();
            Query query;
            if (islast) {
                query = db.collection(node)
                        .document(lastid)
                        .collection("list")
                        .document(id)
                        .collection("list");
            } else {
                query = db.collection(node)
                        .document(id)
                        .collection("list");
            }
    
            query.get()
                    .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
                            dismissProgressDialog();
                            if (task.isSuccessful()) {
    
                                list.clear();
                                int i = 0;
                                boolean match = false;
                                try {
                                    for (DocumentSnapshot snapshot : task.getResult().getDocuments()) {
                                        CardModel mainModel = snapshot.toObject(CardModel.class);
                                        mainModel.setId(snapshot.getId());
                                        if (mainModel.enable) {
                                            boolean onOff=mainModel.cOnOff;
                                            if (mainModel.countries != null
                                                    && mainModel.countries.size() > 0) {
                                                if (!sessionManager.getLocation().isEmpty()) {
                                                    if(onOff) {
                                                        if (mainModel.countries.contains(sessionManager.getLocation())) {
                                                            match = true;
                                                            list.add(mainModel);
                                                        } else {
                                                            list.remove(mainModel);
                                                        }
    
                                                    }else{
                                                        if (mainModel.countries.contains(sessionManager.getLocation())) {
                                                            match = true;
                                                            list.remove(mainModel);
                                                        } else {
                                                            list.add(mainModel);
                                                        }
                                                    }
                                                } else {
                                                    list.add(mainModel);
                                                }
                                            } else {
                                                list.add(mainModel);
                                            }
                                        } else {
                                            list.remove(mainModel);
                                        }
                                        Log.d("view imgs", "data is " + mainModel.toString());
    
                                    }
                                } catch (Exception e) {
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                }
                                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    
                            }
                            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                            dismissProgressDialog();
                        }
                    })
                    .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                          dismissProgressDialog();
                            Toast.makeText(Category_List_Activity.this, e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    })
            ;
        }
    
    }
```

Comment: Please take a look at this link from the official documentation. It will assist you. The code is only working on refresh or restart because you do not have an event listener for firestore. https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen#java

Comment: Do not vandalize your posts. By posting on this site, you've irrevocably granted the Stack Exchange network the right to distribute that content under the [CC BY-SA 4.0 license](//creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/) for as long as it sees fit to do so. For alternatives to deletion, see: [I've thought better of my question; can I delete it?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/what-to-do-instead-of-deleting-question)